# Doesn't += return the newly assigned value?

Tags: java, netbeans

I'm looping over image and summing the values of all pixels. I do this to create an integral image. To keep the last value easily available, I created `the_sum` variable to which I add values for each pixel.

If you know how integral image works, you know that every pixel in such image contains sum of all pixels before *plus* it's own value.

Hence:

```
integral_image[x][y][0] = (the_sum[0]+= (pixel & 0x00FF0000)>>16);
```

I increase the sum and assign it to current pixel. Netbeans IDE, however, warns me that I'm not reading from `the_sum`.

[image: image description]

Something in the algorithm is broken and I'm not sure what is it. Is my approach wrong or is this a false positive report by NetBeans?

To avoid misunderstanding, this is the whole method:

```
  /* Generate an integral image. Every pixel on such image contains sum of colors or all the
     pixels before and itself.
  */
  public static double[][][] integralImage(BufferedImage image) {
    int w = image.getWidth();
    int h = image.getHeight();

    double integral_image[][][] = new double[w][h][3];
    double the_sum[] = new double[3];

    for (int x = 0; x < w; x++) {
      for (int y = 0; y < h; y++) {
        int pixel = image.getRGB(x, y);
        integral_image[x][y][0] = (the_sum[0]+= (pixel & 0x00FF0000)>>16);
        integral_image[x][y][1] = (the_sum[1]+= (pixel & 0x0000FF00)>>8);
        integral_image[x][y][2] = (the_sum[2]+=  pixel & 0x000000FF);
      }
    }

    return integral_image;
  }
```

Comment: And, uhm, what about writing your code in a way that is easier to read? You write code only once but you read it many times; don't make it hard for readers (you included) to understand what it does.

Comment: Just will stay it here - http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-150003.pdf

Comment: @fge Could you more specifically say how would you write it while not touching the efficiency (which is unfortunately still a big issue with computer vision programs)?

Comment: Does the algorithm do what it should?  If so, then you can "safely" ignore netbeans this time.  However, if your code is confusing your IDE, it's probably also confusing other people (like me) who try to help you diagnose it.  If it's not working properly, refactor it so you can see what exactly you're doing.  You can optimize a working algorithm more easily than you can fix an optimized algorithm.

Comment: Using two additions instead would have exactly the same effect (`sum +=...; integral_image +=....`) while making it much more readable. Shorter to write does not necessarily mean faster to execute! What is more this is Java, therefore the JIT is there too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `+=` returns the newly assigned value. It is a false positive from netbeans.

> At run time, the result of the assignment expression is the value of the variable after the assignment has occurred.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.26